# How do I print unicode characters using git format

Tags: git

I want to parse the output of git. To seperate fields I would like to use `U+001D` as a separator.

Does anyone know I can tell gits format to output unicode characters?

Comment: Could you give us sample expected git output?

Comment: e.g. `git --no-pager branch -a --list --format='%(objectname) %(refname)'`